# Appium node sample tests not running

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, automated-tests, appium

I am https://github.com/appium/sample-code

and when I run file at sample-code/sample-code/examples/node/android-simple.js

with command mocha `android-simple.js` attached is the output with error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This Error will come only when your environment is not set properly..

Make Sure that your Target device(Android Emulator) is up and running and device name that you mentioned in desired capabilities are right